# Form.Visible is false after using ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE)

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

Working on a single instance program that minimizes to the icon tray. I noticed that the `Form`'s `Visible` property remained false even though the form is visible on the screen. It seems like the internal workings of the `Form` should detect when it is made visible again by an external source, but it does not. Having `Visible` false causes other controls not to behave correctly.

A workaround is to listen for `WM_SETFOCUS` messages in the `WndProc` method and then force `form.Visible = true;` but I am wondering if there is a better approach to single instance? Using a pipe-listener could be another approach, but it seems overkill.

Here is some code that illustrates the problem. The thread is meant to pretend another program is restoring the program from its minimized state in the icon tray:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo {

public class FormVisibleFalse : Form {

    private const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x7;
    private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    private bool setVisible = true;

    NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    FormWindowState windowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    Button btnIsVisible = new Button { Text = "IsVisible", AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
    IntPtr mainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    public FormVisibleFalse() {
        Text = "Form.Visible = False";
        notifyIcon.MouseClick += notifyIcon_MouseClick;
        notifyIcon.Icon = this.Icon;
        btnIsVisible.Click += btnIsVisible_Click;
        FlowLayoutPanel p = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, WrapContents = false, FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown };
        p.Controls.Add(btnIsVisible);
        p.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "After minimizing the form, click the IsVisible button.", AutoSize = true });
        Controls.Add(p);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        mainWindowHandle = this.Handle;
    }

    void btnIsVisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Form.Visible = " + this.Visible);
    }

    void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        setVisible = false;
        this.Visible = true;
        this.WindowState = windowState;
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
            this.Visible = false;
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            setVisible = true;

            // two seconds later, restore the form.
            // Note: This is just a simple way to illustrate the problem. The actual pinvoke call
            // is made from a second instance of the process that detects if an instance is
            // already running, and restores the main window. A pipe listener could also be used to
            // pass a message telling the running instance to restore, but that's a more complicated
            // solution.
            Thread t = new Thread(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE); // also tried SW_NORMAL and SW_SHOW
                SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowHandle);
            });
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start(); // after this runs, then click the IsVisible button
        }
        else {
            windowState = this.WindowState;
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS && setVisible) {
            setVisible = false;
            // this.Visible = true; // <-- this fixes the problem but is there a more correct way?
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing) {
            notifyIcon.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

}

}
```

Comment: If you don't look for the WM_SETFOCUS message, what do you use to hide the notifyIcon?

Comment: It would seem logical that the `Form` should fire an event when its window state was changed, even by an external source. So it could be put there if that's how things actually worked.

Comment: There is no notification from the OS when a window becomes hidden/visible.  None was deemed necessary since the user can't do anything to change that state, only a program can do that.  The OS is not heavily invested in telling you what you already know.  Without that notification, Winforms doesn't have a shot at updating the property.  Also the reason why there is no StateChanged event, clearly desirable because SizeChanged is an accidental side-effect.  The repro code hides the real intention, use the form's BeginInvoke() method perhaps to set the Visible property.

Comment: Perhaps the [WM_QUERYOPEN message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-queryopen) would be a more appropriate message to listen for.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.A candidate solution is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current solution for a single instance Form that minimizes the the icon tray. Please post a comment if you see any potential issues.

- The form is restored to its previous window state. So if it was `Normal` before minimizing, then it will be `Normal` after, and if it was `Maximized` before then it will be `Maximized` after.
- All child windows and child of child windows are also minimized. The default behavior in Windows is to only minimize the immediate child windows when the main `Form` is minimized for some reason.
- If the program is already running, and the `Form` is `Normal` or `Maximized` then the window is brought to the front. `SW_RESTORE` is not sent.
- If the program is already running, but the `Form` is `Minimized` then `SW_RESTORE` is sent.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo {

public class IconTrayForm : Form {

    private const String TITLE = "IconTrayForm";
    private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    Button btnChildWindow = new Button { Text = "Child Window", AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink, AutoSize = true };
    CheckBox cbMinimizeToIconTray = new CheckBox { Text = "Minimize to Icon Tray", Checked = true, AutoSize = true };
    char ChildTitle = 'A';
    //---
    List<IntPtr> hiddenWindows = new List<IntPtr>();
    NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    bool isRestoring = false; // prevents double-calls

    public IconTrayForm() {
        this.Text = TITLE;
        FlowLayoutPanel p = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown };
        p.Controls.Add(cbMinimizeToIconTray);
        p.Controls.Add(btnChildWindow);
        Controls.Add(p);
        Size = new Size(600,600);
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        btnChildWindow.Click += btnChildWindow_Click;

        notifyIcon.Icon = this.Icon;
        notifyIcon.MouseClick += notifyIcon_MouseClick;
    }

    private void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
                RestoreWindows();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        if (isRestoring)
            return;

        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        FormWindowState ws = this.WindowState;

        if (ws == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
            if (cbMinimizeToIconTray.Checked) {
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;

                HandleUtils.ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_HIDE);
                // windows that are not owned by this parent form will still appear visible and must be hidden:
                hiddenWindows = HandleUtils.GetProcessWindowHandles().Where(h => HandleUtils.IsWindowVisible(h)).ToList();
                foreach (IntPtr h in hiddenWindows) {
                    HandleUtils.ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Form f = this;
            if (f.IsHandleCreated && !f.Visible) {
                RestoreWindows();
            }
        }
    }

    private void RestoreWindows() {
        isRestoring = true;
        try {
        Form f = this;
        // SW_RESTORE seems like the best option. It works to restore minimized back to normal/maximized
        if (f.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
            // the exe calls ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE) which changes the window state from Minimized to Maximized
            // but calling ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE) again then changes the window state from Maximized to Normal
            HandleUtils.ShowWindow(f.Handle, SW_RESTORE);
        }

        foreach (IntPtr h in hiddenWindows)
            HandleUtils.ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW);

        this.hiddenWindows = new List<IntPtr>();
        HandleUtils.SetForegroundWindow(f.Handle); // must do this otherwise the window stays behind

        // Make sure all visible windows are not offscreen. Any offscreen window moved will become the active window.
        //List<IntPtr> visibleWindows = HandleUtils.GetProcessWindowHandles().Where(h => HandleUtils.IsWindowVisible(h)).ToList();
        //foreach (IntPtr h in visibleWindows) {
        //  FormEx.EnsureVisible(h);
        //}

        this.Visible = true; // for some reason this.Visible stays false even though ShowWindow is called
        // this causes problems when a control is added to a TabPage.Controls.Add(...) that the content is never displayed

        if (notifyIcon != null)
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        } finally {
            isRestoring = false;
        }
    }

    void btnChildWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChildForm f = new ChildForm(ChildTitle.ToString());
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        ChildTitle++;
        f.Owner = this;
        Point p = this.Location;
        p.Offset(0, 100);
        f.Location = p;
        f.Show();
    }

    private class ChildForm : Form {
        Button btnChildWindow = new Button { Text = "Child Window", AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink, AutoSize = true };
        char ChildTitle = 'A';

        public ChildForm(String title) {
            this.Text = title;
            Controls.Add(btnChildWindow);
            btnChildWindow.Click += btnChildWindow_Click;
        }

        void btnChildWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ChildForm f = new ChildForm(this.Text + "." + ChildTitle);
            f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            ChildTitle++;
            f.Owner = this;
            Point p = this.Location;
            p.Offset(0, 70);
            f.Location = p;
            f.Show();
        } 
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing) {
            notifyIcon.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        // first detect if an instance is already running
        bool isMainWindowRunning = false;
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();

        try {
            int processId = currentProcess.Id;
            String processName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath);
            //String processName = currentProcess.ProcessName;
            processes.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName(processName));
            processes.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName(processName + ".vshost")); // for debugging

            //var ata = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)[0] as AssemblyTitleAttribute;
            String title2 = TITLE; //Application.ProductName;
            IntPtr mainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            foreach (Process p in processes) {
                if (p.Id == processId)
                    continue;

                IntPtr ptr = p.MainWindowHandle;
                if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    String title = p.MainWindowTitle ?? "";
                    // Possibly there are multiple exe with the same name, so safe guard by comparing the title
                    if (!title.StartsWith(title2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        continue;

                    mainWindowHandle = ptr;
                    isMainWindowRunning = true;
                    goto FOUND_MAIN_WINDOW_HANDLE;
                }
                else {
                    // p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero when the form is minimized to the icon tray.
                    IList<IntPtr> list = HandleUtils.GetProcessWindowHandles(p.Id);
                    foreach (IntPtr h in list) {
                        String title = HandleUtils.GetWindowText(h) ?? "";
                        // potentially the class name could be used to identify a Form if the title was blank
                        //Application.WindowsFormsVersion == "WindowsForms10"
                        //String className = User32.GetClassName(h) ?? "";
                        if (!title.StartsWith(title2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            continue;

                        mainWindowHandle = h;
                        isMainWindowRunning = true;
                        goto FOUND_MAIN_WINDOW_HANDLE;
                    }
                }
            }
            FOUND_MAIN_WINDOW_HANDLE:

            if (isMainWindowRunning) {
                WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = HandleUtils.GetPlacement(mainWindowHandle);
                if (wp.showCmd == ShowWindowCommands.Normal || wp.showCmd == ShowWindowCommands.Maximized)
                    HandleUtils.SetForegroundWindow(mainWindowHandle);
                else
                    HandleUtils.ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);

                return;
            }
        } finally {
            currentProcess.Dispose();
            foreach (Process p in processes)
                p.Dispose();
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Demo.IconTrayForm());
    }
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT {
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public ShowWindowCommands showCmd;
    public System.Drawing.Point ptMinPosition;
    public System.Drawing.Point ptMaxPosition;
    public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
}

public enum ShowWindowCommands : int {
    Hide = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    Minimized = 2,
    Maximized = 3,
}

public static class HandleUtils {

    public static IList<IntPtr> GetProcessWindowHandles() {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()) {
            return GetProcessWindowHandles(p);
        }       
    }

    public static IList<IntPtr> GetProcessWindowHandles(int processId) {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(processId)) {
            return GetProcessWindowHandles(p);
        }
    }

    public static IList<IntPtr> GetProcessWindowHandles(System.Diagnostics.Process p) {
        var handles = new List<IntPtr>();
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread thread in p.Threads) {
            EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id,
                (hWnd, lParam) => {
                    handles.Add(hWnd);
                    return true;
                },
                IntPtr.Zero);
        }       
        return handles;
    }

    private delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

    public static WINDOWPLACEMENT GetPlacement(IntPtr hwnd) {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
        GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref placement);
        return placement;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
    public static String GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
}
```